How add events to Confluence calendar with JS API?
I'm trying to find any information on how I can create an event in Team Calendar in Confluence, but I can't find anything useful for JS. The official documentation is missing, and there are only suggestions for workarounds, which do not suit me.
I've gone through all the possible documentation and advice that I could find online. It turned out to be insufficient. Most people have encountered the same problem and are just waiting for the creators of Confluence to add this feature, but this issue has been dragging on since 2011!

This is not yet possible. A calendar event creation API for Confluence has been suggested for over 10 years but is not yet on Atlassian’s roadmap.
